# Smack API - How to encrypt messages

Tags: java, encryption, xmpp, smack

I have this ConnectionConfiguration

```
ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration = new ConnectionConfiguration(host, port);
connectionConfiguration.setCompressionEnabled(false);
connectionConfiguration.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);
connectionConfiguration.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
connectionConfiguration.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
connectionConfiguration.setTruststorePath(TRUST_STORE_PATH);
connectionConfiguration.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
```

Then I'm connecting

```
connection = new XMPPConnection(connectionConfiguration);
```

Then sending message

```
Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
msg.setBody(text);
connection.sendPacket(msg);
```

What should I change to encrypt messages? I need something like:

```
key = connection.generateEncryptionKeys()
```

and

```
msg.encrypt(key)
```

I'm using Smack library.

Comment: Encrypt? Do you want to implement a specifix [XEP](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/)? Smack implements [some XEPs](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html). Which of these do you want to use?

Comment: @LutzHorn I don't know which XEP is it, I found [this](http://xmpp.org/internet-drafts/attic/draft-ietf-xmpp-e2e-00.html#messages)

Comment: I want to encrypt my messages with combination of keys. Also on receiving client I will have public and private key. When I send message, I will encrypt it using my combination of keys, and decrypt on other client use their combination of keys. Like RSA

Comment: The XEP you link to was only a draft which has never been acceptes. Smack does not seem to implement it. Try to use one of the XEPs that Smack implements. If none of them are OK, you can take part in the development of Smack and implement your favorite XEP.